# Upload a PDF vector in qgis

Tags: qgis, pdf

I have a PDF file that my partners gave me, this file has the exact vertex of the study area and heights lines, so I need to overlap it with some satellite image, so I can compare with the map in paper and make polygons and paint a geological map, the thing is I can't add the data in form of vectors because it appears all flipped, west in the east and north in the south, how can I load a pdf file as a vector layer without this issue?

Comment: It might help if you add the result of gdalsrsinfo from the command line, and the CRS your layer and project uses.